# Login page too many redirects

Tags: plugin-development

I have a custom plugin that handles the login and verification of customers. It creates default WordPress users with custom usermeta. But as an admin whenever I try to access the wp-admin dashboard on my live site I get an error page with too many redirects. This however works on my local dev site. Below is the function that fires after logging in and gives the error.

```
    function redirect_to_lvkg_login() {

        if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {

            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                lvkg_redirect_logged_in_user();
                exit;
            }

            $login_url = home_url( 'login' );

            if (!empty($_REQUEST['redirect_to'])) {
                $login_url = add_query_arg('redirect_to', $_REQUEST['redirect_to'], $login_url);
            }
            
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['checkemail'])) {
                $login_url = add_query_arg('checkemail', $_REQUEST['checkemail'], $login_url);
            }

            if (!empty($_REQUEST['verify']) && lvkg_check_code($_REQUEST['verify'], 'verif_id')) {
                
                $user_id = lvkg_check_code($_REQUEST['verify'], 'verif_id');

                $user_stat = get_user_meta($user_id, 'status', true);
                $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

                $args = array('login' => $user_info->user_login);
                $args['verify'] = ($user_stat == "unverified") ? 'verified' : 'already_verified';

                if($user_stat == "unverified")
                    update_user_meta($user_id, 'status', 'verified');

                $login_url = add_query_arg($args, $login_url);

            }

            wp_redirect($login_url);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

```
function lvkg_redirect_logged_in_user($redirect_to = null ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (user_can($user,'manage_options')) {
        if ($redirect_to) {
            wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
            exit;
        } else {
            wp_redirect(admin_url());
            exit;
        }

    } else {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something, or could this be a problem with my hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin()) {
                lvkg_redirect_logged_in_user();
                exit;
            }
```

!is_admin() will make sure that this function is not called if a user is already in wp-admin or has been successfully redirected to wp-admin.
Without this check after every redirection to wp-admin, this function will be called again lvkg_redirect_logged_in_user(); hence creating an infinite loop.